# Some noise when attempting to produce sound wia external DAC for esp323

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32, platformio

I am trying to make a voice changing device with **esp32** board (**PlatformIO + ArduinoIDE**).

I have:

1. external microphone on input
2. esp32, to process voice (internal ADC is used for incoming signal - **I2S protocol**)
3. external DAC (PCM5102) to output changed voice (**I2S protocol**)

My scheme is working. The *sound goes to micro -> adc (I2S) -> process on esp32 -> dac (I2S)*. But after some time of working (~1 min) I begin to hear a terrible loid fading **noise** (decay period ~3 sec). Then noise appears once every 5 seconds constantly.

**What could be the problem? Maybe I'm setting up adc and dac incorrectly?**

Connection scheme (connection is made on a **breadboard**):
[image]

Code:

```
#include <driver/i2s.h>

#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE     100000
#define I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN     1024

#define ADC_INPUT           ADC1_CHANNEL_4 //pin 32

#define I2S_DATA_PIN        GPIO_NUM_22 // DIN
#define I2S_LRCK_PIN        GPIO_NUM_25 // LCK
#define I2S_BCLK_PIN        GPIO_NUM_26 // BCK


/*
 * Configure ADC.
 */
void i2sInputInit() {
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
            .mode = (i2s_mode_t) (I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_ADC_BUILT_IN),
            .sample_rate =  I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,              // The format of the signal using ADC_BUILT_IN
            .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, // is fixed at 12bit, stereo, MSB
            .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
            .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,
            .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
            .dma_buf_count = 2048,
            .dma_buf_len = I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN,
            .use_apll = true,
            .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
            .fixed_mclk = 0
    };

    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_set_adc_mode(ADC_UNIT_1, ADC_INPUT);
//    i2s_adc_enable(I2S_NUM_0);
//    adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC_INPUT, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11);
}


/*
 * Configure DAC.
 */
void i2sOutputInit() {

    // Initialize I2S
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
            .mode = (i2s_mode_t) (I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
            .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
            .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
            .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
            .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,
            .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
            .dma_buf_count = 2048,
            .dma_buf_len = I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN,
            .use_apll = false,
            .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
            .fixed_mclk = 0
    };
    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_1, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);

    // Configure I2S pins
    i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
            .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK_PIN,
            .ws_io_num = I2S_LRCK_PIN,
            .data_out_num = I2S_DATA_PIN,
            .data_in_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE,
    };
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_1, &pin_config);
}


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    i2sInputInit();
    i2sOutputInit();
}


void loop() {
    size_t bytes_read;
    size_t bytes_written;

    int *int_buffer = (int *) malloc(I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN * sizeof(int));
    i2s_read(I2S_NUM_0, int_buffer, I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN * sizeof(int), &bytes_read, portMAX_DELAY);
    applyEffect(int_buffer);
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_1, int_buffer, I2S_DMA_BUF_LEN * sizeof(int), &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    free(int_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Separate the problem. Try and output a pure sine wave to the ADC and see if that is still noisy. If it is then chances are the fault is in your breadboarded electronics. BTW if the microphone can hear the amplified output of your speaker then howl round acoustic feedback may be causing your problem. Use an earpiece to eliminate that risk.

Comment: @MartinBrown,the problem is that the sound is uninterrupted most of the time, but in some moments it has distortions. Distortions are periodical, so I guess that it is more code problem rather than hardware. E.g. two serial buffers overlap each other or smth like that.
As for earpiece, I use them.

Saying about sine wave, you mean internal generator? Or it can be done somehow else?

Comment: Load a buffer with a sine wave and output that. If the problem is in the output logic or the drive electronics then you will still have a problem. If not then you can be confident that your output code is playing what is in the output buffer correctly.

Comment: How do you get the I2S input if your `i2s_adc_enable(I2S_NUM_0);` is comment out?

Comment: BTW, for an analog mic, the bandwidth won't be better than 20kHz(maybe even lower), so to have a sampling rate of 100000 is just waste ESP32 resource, 20*2 = 40k sampling rate should be sufficient.

Comment: @hcheung, honestly, I don't know why it works without `i2s_adc_enable(I2S_NUM_0);` but it works. If I uncomment it, I still have the same problem. 

I changed the sampling rate to 44.1kHz. I am interested, why we need double a bandwidth of mic to get sufficient sampling rate, can we set it to 20kHz? Also, why does a sampling rate of 100kHz seem to sound better?

Comment: Sorry at the first I thought your code is not working, but after re-read your post, I realised that you had problem with noise. I wonder whether the noise has anyting to do with the power rail. Have you tried to power MAX9814 with a separate battery to just test it out? 20000*2 is based on [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem). The assumption of getting better quality is right if you had a high quality input audio, but in the case of MAX9814, it really doesn't matter much. You can test it and see  yourself.

Comment: @MartinBrown, I loaded a .wav file in SPIFFS and the sound is good, no distortions.

Comment: @hcheung, thank you for theorem ref. I have tried to power MAX9814 with a phone charger micro-usb but it doesn't work. Then I tried to do it with DAC and got the same - nothing works. However, I noticed that if I just switch off (power and pins) mic from esp32, I still can hear the noise. This makes me think that mic has nothing to do with it.

Comment: OK. SO it looks like playback is reliable. That means that the input may be the problem so now create a version that just records what it sees from the microphone verbatim and see if that otherwise unprocessed digital data is noise free. There is a distinct chance that  your problem is crosstalk between the relatively noisy digital CPU environment and the analogue low signal levels of the microphone. Some small inductors on its supply rails and a decoupling capacitor may help here. I remain puzzled by why it works for about a minute and then has periodicity of 5s. maybe some buffer runs out.